# In SQL Server, select char(1) 'A' and not 'a'

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a table that has a column of datatype `char(1)`.

In the table the use of 'A' has one meaning while 'a' has a different meaning.

How do I query for only 'A' and not receive values of 'a'?

I have searched and found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177545.aspx) and looked on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/). I was unable to change to suit my purpose.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because SQL Server is case insensitive from default.

Add "COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS" to your query:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columnName = 'a' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

or change definition of column in your table:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
ALTER COLUMN columnName CHAR(1)
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Comment: Thanks works great.  I will mark as answer as soon as it lets me.